# Thanos' 'situation' at the end of Infinity War

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Spoliers ahead -

So Thanos had all the six stones and with a snap he made half the population vanished. But, those who got vanished we're randomly selected.

So this could have included Thanos himself too, right?

Now, Dr. Strange was able to see all the different possibilities.

After getting the time stone,

- Was Thanos able to see all possibilities in which he could erase half
  the population *and* save himself?
- Or maybe use any infinity stone to save himself?

Did Thanos do anything particular to make himself safe? Or was he actually willing to even let himself die to *make the universe better?*